# Laravel 4 generate not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am new to frameworks please help me out with this.
I am trying to create a file in controller using generate. The following is the command

```
php artisan generate:controller features
```

it gives me the error

```
[InvalidArgumentException]
```

There are no command defined in the "generate" namespace

Comment: Did you install the [package](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Laravel-4-Generators) that provides this command ?

Comment: @Andre No please tell me the steps to do it..

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The generate command is from the [JeffreyWay/Laravel-4-Generators](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Laravel-4-Generators) package, to install it you have to execute

```
composer require way/generators 2.*
```

And then add this line to your `app/config/app.php` in the Service Providers array:

```
'Way\Generators\GeneratorsServiceProvider'
```

After it just execute

```
php artisan
```

And check if you have the following commands available:

```
generate
  generate:controller          Generate a controller
  generate:migration           Generate a new migration
  generate:model               Generate a model
  generate:pivot               Generate a pivot table
  generate:publish-templates   Copy generator templates for user modification
  generate:resource            Generate a new resource
  generate:scaffold            Scaffold a new resource (with boilerplate)
  generate:seed                Generate a database table seeder
  generate:view                Generate a view
```

Answer (score 1):

By following the above procedure you might sometimes face this kind of error:

```
{"error":{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException",
```

To avoid it be sure to do "composer update" before following the procedure.

Answer (score -2):

Try php artisan controller:make features

Answer (score -3):

The correct command is:

```
php artisan controller:make features
```