# Generate package is not working on Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to run this command and migrate users_create_table.

```
php artisan generate:migrate users_create_table
```

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22478135/laravel-4-generate-not-working) but failed.

Comment: Do you use Laravel 5? If yes, have you installed the generators package? (https://github.com/laracasts/Laravel-5-Generators-Extended)

Comment: yes i installed it already. But it is not working. i dont know why is that. anyway from "php artisan make:migration create_users_table" i did my work. Thank for your answer.

Comment: What error does `php artisan generate:migrate users_create_table` give you? Edit: I understand that you already solved it without the generators package.

Comment: generate package does not exist error. I did many things on internet. But it not fix yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Laravel 5, you don't need a third party generator package to create migrations (or most other components of your application). You can use the `artisan make` command.

To create a migration you need to use:

```
php artisan make:migration create_users_table
```

There are a number of generators provided by Artisan by default, which you can see by running `php artisan`.

```
make:command            Create a new command class
make:console            Create a new Artisan command
make:controller         Create a new resource controller class
make:event              Create a new event class
make:job                Create a new job class
make:listener           Create a new event listener class
make:middleware         Create a new middleware class
make:migration          Create a new migration file
make:model              Create a new Eloquent model class
make:policy             Create a new policy class
make:provider           Create a new service provider class
make:request            Create a new form request class
make:seeder             Create a new seeder class
make:test               Create a new test class
```

Comment: yes! I got my solution from your answer. can i know how use generate package in laravel5? Sometimes it will be important to my further works. Thank you!

Comment: With Laravel 5, you'll need the updated Laravel 5 Generators Extended package https://github.com/laracasts/Laravel-5-Generators-Extended

Comment: I have tried it . But i am failed due to some reason. It may be my hand mistake. I'll check it once again. Thank you for your reply.